# sólo quiero que filtre los registros por fecha

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin, filtro

No se cómo hacer que filtre por fecha este formulario, podrían ayudarme? no se cómo anexar bien el código, no me lo permite, aqui anexo un drive con el código, disculpen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SDhVWS6GI72eqtFf8e18W-tblJon179p/view?usp=sharing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], además te sugiero hacer el [tour], un comentario: *el código mínimo necesario para poderte ayudar va en la pregunta*, no nos mandes a un enlace

Comment: Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.

Comment: siempre me aparece ese error

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar enviando por POST los valores que has optenido del formulario al PHP que se encarga de realizar la consulta a la base de datos. Por ejemplo:

```php
<?php
  $fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
  $fecha_fin = $_POST['fecha_final'];
  $sql="SELECT * FROM Historial_Pago WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '".$fecha_inicio."' AND '".$fecha_fin."'";
  $result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
?>
```

Y de esa manera ya filtras por fecha.

Comment: Me parece que el juego de comillas y concatenación que tienes no es correcta, checa

Comment: @BetaM listo modifique el codigo, gracias por tu observación.

Comment: perfecto ya quedó :)